# Aggregate Boundary repository/service design

Tags: design, domain-driven-design, repository, domain-model, aggregate

I am trying to apply DDD to the design of a Release Management system.

### **Domain Entities**

- `Project`: The project/product/system.
- `ProjectEnvironment`: The environments (Test, Staging, Prod) that exist for this project.  Each project has its own defined environments.
- `ProjectVersion`: A specific version of the project. This would be associated with a deployment package.

  [image: Class diagram of entities]

### **Aggregate Boundary**

From this I would have `Project` be the aggregate root and `ProjectEnvironment` and `ProjectVersion` be aggregates of `Project`.  Neither of these can exist without `Project`.

### **Repository**

I would then only have a `ProjectRepository` which would provide persisted `Projects` with all the included `ProjectVersion` and `ProjectEnvironment` aggregates (and consequently can only be accessed through their respective `Project`).

### **Questions**

1. Should there be a `VersionRepository` and a `EnvironmentRepository`?  A `GetVersionById()` method on the `ProductRepository` sounds wrong.  But then wouldn't supplying multiple repositories threaten the aggregate boundary?
2. Should there be a 'ProjectService' which would handle and validate the aggregates using the three repositories?  In order to safeguard against invalid data, client code would only be able to reference the 'ProjectService'.

Answer (score 1):

If your `ProjectVersion` does not make sense without a `Project` then there's no need to have a repository of them. All versions for a project should be contained wtihin the aggregate. Furthermore your aggregate itself is where your validation should take place. This ensures that your aggregate is always consistent and valid.

```
public class Project {
    private List<ProjectVersion> Versions = new List<ProjectVersion>();

    public void AddVersion(Version version, string notes) {
        if(Versions.Any(x => x.Version > version)) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid version given. Version cannot be lower than the highest current version.");
        }
        Versions.Add(new ProjectVersion(this, version, notes));
    }
}
```